# Find the value of $x_2$ for $x_{n+2} = {5\over 2}x_{n+1} + x_n$ to be convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

> Given a recurrence relation:
>   $$
> x_{n+2} = {5\over 2}x_{n+1} + x_n\\
> x_1 = a\\
> n\in\Bbb N
> $$
>   Find the value of $x_2$ for $x_n$ to be convergent and evaluate:
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n
> $$

First assume the limits exists, then it must follow:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = L \implies 2L = 5L + 2L \iff L = 0
$$

The only possible value for the limit is $L = 0$.

Then I proceeded with writing down a characteristic equation for the recurrence:
$$
\lambda^2 = {5\over 2}\lambda + 1 \\
2\lambda^2 = 5\lambda + 2\\
2\lambda^2 - 5\lambda - 2 = 0
$$

So the roots are given by:
$$
\lambda = \frac{5 \pm \sqrt{41}}{4}
$$

Given that fact the closed form of the recurrence is as follows:
$$
x_n = c_1\lambda_1^n + c_2\lambda_2^n
$$

Or writing down the initial conditions:
$$
c_1\lambda_1^1 + c_2\lambda_2^1 = a \\
c_1\lambda_1^2 + c_2\lambda_2^2 = x_2
$$

From here I'm not sure where to go. $c_1, c_2$ are still unknown and will remain unknown unless $x_2$ is given which is a circular dependency. The answer section suggests that:
$$
x_2 = a\frac{5-\sqrt{41}}{4}
$$

How do I obtain that result? Please note this problem is from limits section, and I would like to stick to the simplest possible solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1 > 0$ and $\lambda_2 < 0$.  It's clear from OP's finding $$\lambda = \frac{5 \pm \sqrt{41}}{4}$$ that $\lambda_1 \in \left(\cfrac{11}{4},3\right)$ and $\lambda_2 \in \left(-\cfrac12,-\cfrac14\right)$.  Therefore, $\lambda_1^n \to \infty$ and $\lambda_2^n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.  Since $(x_n)_n$ has to be convergent, $c_1 = 0$.  The system of linear equations $$c_1\lambda_1^1 + c_2\lambda_2^1 = a \\
c_1\lambda_1^2 + c_2\lambda_2^2 = x_2$$ then becomes
\begin{cases}
c_2\lambda_2 &= a \\
c_2\lambda_2^2 &= x_2.
\end{cases}

Then $c_2 = x_2 / \lambda_2^2$ and $a = c_2\lambda_2 = x_2 / \lambda_2$.  Hence $$x_2 = \lambda_2 a = -\frac{\sqrt{41}-5}{4} a$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you please elaborate on where those intervals for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ come from?

Comment: $\sqrt{41} \in (6,7)$

Comment: Thank you once more, it's all clear now.